# Did Cordova 7 change the default status bar color?

Tags: android, cordova, statusbar

I've got a Cordova project that is **not** using the Status bar plugin. When compiled and running on my Galaxy S7, it always used to have a black status bar.

Now I've configured a new computer and compiled the app again, and now it has a greenish blue status bar.

On the old computer I was using Cordova 6.4.0, on the new I have 7.0.1.

Is the change in status bar color a change in Cordova, or is it something I did?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Only see that change in the config. https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-statusbar/  I have a recent app I just compiled and it is still black, and I have black in the config.

Comment: @RegencySoftware, sorry could you elaborate? I don't see any change in any config.xml file, nor in the cordova-plugin-statusbar documentation. Note that I am not using the Statusbar plugin.